# Android Background Job Service on CoroutineScope and Dispatcher.IO

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

#### Context

I'm trying to update a couple of background Job in Android 6. The main goal is to make the work done by the background job light and non ui thread blocking. So I decided to some things:

- GlobalScope may be a bad idea since a dying thread will terminate the others. So CoroutineScope will to the trick
- Since I need I/O and Network stuff done, I need a thread pool designed for those tasks. So I'll use Dispatchers.IO
- The work of the bound JobServices are designed for "fire and forget". The app doesn't care - so I'll just launch the job instead of waiting for the output of an async

#### Code

All together I designed the following JobService class as a template for others to be migrated or implemented. Since the job is shedulded the class will return false to the inherited functions.

```
import android.app.job.JobParameters
import android.app.job.JobService
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class TestJobService : JobService() {

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            // Fire and Forget
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

#### Questions

If you want to answer please use the number of the question.

1. Is CoroutineScope a good idea?
2. I'm getting errors from the main thread "I/art: Note: end time exceeds epoch:" - this is confusing and could indicate that the JobService does to much work on the UI thread. But I have no errors from the choreographer which should normally be the case if the UI is in trouble.
3. Is it a bad idea to return false in the JobService functions

#### Currently used Links

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-i-getting-the-background-3e0e54d20bb
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-ii-getting-started-3bff117176dd
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-iii-real-work-2ba8a2ec2f45
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv?hl=de#coroutinescope
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#extract-function-refactoring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The only thing your usage of `CoroutineScope` does is provide the `IO` dispatcher. As it stands, if any of the work done in the coroutine throws an exception, the whole scope will be cancelled. That may be a problem if you are launching multiple coroutines from within it. If you do care about that you would also need to set it up with a [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html): `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) + SupervisorJob()`.
2. It's hard to identify the meaning of that error without your actual code. From researching quickly, if you do something that should only occur on the main thread (like accessing certain Android components perhaps), that may cause that error. Perhaps inspect your code for those occurances and wrap it in a:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { ... }
```

But again this is just a guess without having any actual code.

3. The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService#onStartJob(android.app.job.JobParameters)) indicate for `onStartJob`:

> The system holds a wakelock on behalf of your app as long as your job is executing. This wakelock is acquired before this method is invoked, and is not released until either you call jobFinished(android.app.job.JobParameters, boolean), or after the system invokes onStopJob(android.app.job.JobParameters) to notify your job that it is being shut down prematurely.

> Returning false from this method means your job is already finished. The system's wakelock for the job will be released, and onStopJob(android.app.job.JobParameters) will not be invoked.

And according to the [wakelock docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock),

> A wake lock is a mechanism to indicate that your application needs to have the device stay on.

So no, it does not seem correct to return `false` from `onStartJob` as the `JobService` will not properly maintain the wakelock. To remedy this, you should return `true` from this method, and upon completion of the coroutine, you should call [`jobFinished`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService#jobFinished(android.app.job.JobParameters,%20boolean)) to indicate the job has completed all of its work.

For [`onStopJob`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService#jobFinished(android.app.job.JobParameters,%20boolean)), the return values:

> true to indicate to the JobManager whether you'd like to reschedule this job based on the retry criteria provided at job creation-time; or false to end the job entirely. Regardless of the value returned, your job must stop executing.

For this case it's hard to tell what is the correct value based on your snippet. You should be able to figure out which is correct based on your use case. In this method you should be cancelling your previously created `CoroutineScope`. You will need to maintain a reference to the scope in order to do this.